# Batch Script-How to continue reading in IF function even with | symbol in text?

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, scripting

I am using IF function to compare and echo it into a file.
I have notice that it does not read line with "|"

File:

```
Running: Microsoft Windows 7|2008
ExampleExampleExampleExampleExample
ExampleExampleExampleExampleExample
ExampleExampleExampleExampleExample
Running: Microsoft Windows 2008
ExampleExampleExampleExampleExample
Running: Microsoft Windows 2008
ExampleExampleExampleExampleExample
Running: Microsoft Windows XP|2003
ExampleExampleExampleExampleExample
ExampleExampleExampleExampleExample
Running: Microsoft Windows 7|2008
```

Code:

```
@echo off
set local

set "file1=C:\Users\Intern3\Downloads\Nmap\1.txt"
echo %date%, %time% > report1.csv

FOR /f "usebackq delims=" %%a IN ("%file1%") DO (CALL :process %%a)

goto :eof

:process
IF "%~1"=="Running:" echo "Operating System:", %~2 >> report1.csv
```

I need all the result with the keyword starting with Running:
Please help thanks.

Comment: when `CALL :process %%a` is expanded it becomes `CALL :process Running: Microsoft Windows 7|2008` which is like a pipe, so you need to quote or escape the pipe symbol

Answer (score 1):

As indicated by Lưu Vĩnh Phúc, your poblem happens when the `%%a` is expanded to generate the `call` command to execute. This generated command includes a pipe operator. The simplest way to avoid it is to avoid the `call`, splitting the input line using the `tokens` clause of the `for /f` command.

`tokens=1,*` means that using spaces or tabs (the default), tokenize the read line and retrieve the first token into `%%a` (the indicated replaceable parameter) and the rest of the line (the `*`) into `%%b` (the next character)

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "file=input.txt"

    > "report.csv" (
        echo %date% %time%
        for /f "usebackq tokens=1,*" %%a in ("%file%") do (
            if "%%a"=="Running:" echo "Operating System:", %%b
        )
    )
```